# Difference between isEmpty() & isEmpty in Laravel 6

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6

When I query a model to check if a field exists I can use `$model->isEmpty()`. But on some instances isEmpty() gives 500 internal server error. Bu if I use `$model->isEmpty` on those instances it works.

Is this related to the query type?

Comment: What does the error say? 500 server errors usually have a message associated with them, which can be found in your logs, or displayed as an error if you have errors enabled (which you should during development)

Comment: Found one of those errors in the laravel log. `local.ERROR: Call to undefined method App\ProductTemplate::isEmpty() {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method App\\ProductTemplate::isEmpty()`

Comment: That would do it. `ProductTemplate` is a `Model`, and models don't have `isEmpty()`. If you have a `Collection`, then `isEmpty()` is available, like `ProductTemplate::get()->isEmpty()` is ok, but `ProductTemplate::first()->isEmpty()` is not.

Comment: So, I do `$template = ProductTemplate::with('details.hardwareCategory')->find($id);` then `$template->isEmpty()` but it fails. When I do `$template->isEmpty` it works.

Comment: `isEmpty` (without the `()`) is not doing anything. It's a property, and when a model doesn't have a property, it just returns `null`. If you can just do `if(!$template){ ... }` instead of `if($template->isEmpty()){ ... }`, since find will return an instance of `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tim :)